# Getting "toml.decoder.TomlDecodeError: Key name found without value." while deploying streamlit app on Heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli, streamlit, heroku-api

While I got this error from logs: [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWo2U.png)
[image]

When I visited toml.decoder.py file I found the location of line where this error was raised [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAddD.png)
[image]

How can I solve this issue. I was trying to deploy a streamlit web app on heroku.

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. Found anything on this ?

Comment: Not yet, but as soon as I figure it out I will post the solution here. Kindly do, the same from your side.